# How do you visualize a bar plot with many labels in Jupyter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization

[image]

I have a counter with 158 rows (key-value) pairs and I am trying to visualize them in Jupyter. The problem, as you can see from the image, is that the x-axis squishes all the label names and its unreadable. Any idea how to fix this so I can see the value for each label?

Code:

```
def draw_graph_of_appeal_frequency(df):   
    cnt = count_appeal_frequency(df.TONE)

    plt.bar(cnt.keys(), cnt.values(), orientation='vertical', align='edge')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.bar(cnt.keys(), cnt.values(), orientation="vertical", align='edge')
plt.xticks(range(len(cnt.keys())), labels, rotation=90, fontsize = 5, ha='right')
```

I tried with 158 bars and was able to have all of the xticks be readable, small but readable.